# What is this connector

Tags: connector, identification

I was hoping someone could tell me what type of connector this is.

This is in an arcade cabinet connecting the speaker wires to a Sega amp (part number sj25-0361-01).

The width from outside edge to outside edge of the housing for both pins is .29 inches.

Thanks in advance!

[image: photo of connector]
[image]

Comment: how big is it??

Comment: appears to be a molex connector

Comment: Part numbers or specs of the parts this connects to may help as well and if you measure the dimensions as accurately as you can and provide a diagram.  If you can't do that, put a common coin or banana in the picture for scale.  Show a picture of the connector/header that this plugs into.  Don't really use a banana.  Use a commonly known coin.

Comment: The cabinet itself isn't really relevant since the insides have been replaced from another machine - however, I found the part number of the amp it connects to and added to the question.

Comment: Thank you @jsotola for adding the image of the amp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Hirose connector from the EnerBee Series DF22

Take a look at part [DF22C-2S-7.92C](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF22C-2S-7.92C/H123151-ND/4282553)

[image]

Here is a link to the Datasheet. https://www.hirose.com/product/en/download_file/key_name/DF22/category/Catalog/doc_file_id/31682/?file_category_id=4&item_id=43&is_series=1

Comment: That really looks like it could be the one.  Thank you, never would have come up with Hirose on my own!

Answer (score 2):

That's an AMP Universal Power connector. Sega used them on the Naomi cabinets.

The two pin housing to plug into that board is part #176271, and the pins are #175151 (or 175152 for larger wire). These are female pins for the male plug. Digikey should have them.

See https://wiki.arcadeotaku.com/w/AMP_Universal_Power for more info.

Comment: Yep, there's a drawing here <https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=176271&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English>